# Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 46, column 38)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
Resources:
  CloudNetaVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CloudNeta-VPC

  CloudNetaIGW:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CloudNeta-IGW

  CloudNetaIGWAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCgatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref CloudNetaIGW
      VpcId: !Ref CloudNetaVPC

  CloudNetaPublicRT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref CloudNetaVPC
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CloudNeta-Public-RT

  DefaultPublicRoute:
    Type: AWs::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref CloudNetaPublicRT
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref CloudNetaIGW

  CloudNetaPublicSN:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref CloudNetaVPC
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CloudNeta-Public-SN
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAzs '']

  CloudNetaPublicSNRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
       RouteTableId: !Ref CloudNetaPublicRT
       SubnetId: !Ref CloudNetaPublicSN

  CloudNetaSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Groupdescription: Enable SSH access
      VpcId: !Ref CloudNetaVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CloudNeta-SG

  CloudNetaEC2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-03db74b70e1da9c56
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: TEST-RSA
      SecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref CloudNetaSecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CloudNeta-EC2
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !sub |
            #!/bin/bash
            yum install httpd -y
            systemctl start httpd
            echo "<h1>Test Web Server</h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

I'm making CloudFormation, but there's an error. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
AvailabilityZone: !Select [ 0, !GetAzs '']
```

it should be:

```
AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !Ref AWS::GetAZs '']
```